# Не отображается папка Диаграммы Баз данных в Visual Studio 2017

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2017

Подскажите почему нет папки в Обозревателе объектов SQL SERVER папки Диаграммы Баз данных?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Инструменты для создания диаграмм баз данных были убраны из версий Visual Studio, вышедших после 2012. Вы можете:

- Установить SQL Server Management Studio, она поддерживает работу с диаграммами (ее можно скачать [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017), также она входит в состав пакетов "SQL Server Express with tools")
- Создать на основе базы данных модель Entity Framework или типизированный DataSet ADO.NET. Эти инструменты предоставляют функционал, похожий на диаграммы баз данных.

Источник: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/67403/database-diagram-folder-missing.html